# TableView showing empty table

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on two FXML files, the main frame and a table. When I click the "Logs" button, the table defined in the FXML file must be added to an anchorpane in the frame. But the problem is the data from the database does not show in the table's cells. It just shows a blank table. I tried loading the table directly from another stage(without having to click a button) and the data shows, but why is it that the data does not show when I call it from the controller? I think that the method I created to load the data from the database is not adding the data to the right instance of the table but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've been working on this one for two days and can't seem to find a good answer online. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Here's my code for Main.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/AdminLogin.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    Stage primaryStage;// STAGE FOR ADMIN HOME
    Stage stage;//STAGE FOR LOGIN

    //VARIABLES FOR LOGIN STAGE
    @FXML TextField usernameTF;
    @FXML PasswordField passwordTF;
    @FXML Hyperlink forgotPW;
    @FXML Button loginB;
    @FXML Label superLabel;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @FXML private TableView table;
    @FXML private AnchorPane innerAP;
    @FXML private Button populateB;

    private MySQLConnection adminCon = new MySQLConnection();
    private PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm algo;
    private LogWriter logWriter = new LogWriter();

    private String rawPassword;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    //DB ATTRIBUTES
    private String host;
    private String dbUsername;
    private String dbPassword;

    public Controller()
    {
        //GET MYSQL CONNECTION SETTINGS FROM H2 LOCAL DB
        H2Connection h2Connection = new H2Connection();
        h2Connection.loadDriver();
        h2Connection.connectToDB();
        h2Connection.doSomething("select *from connectionSettings");
        h2Connection.query();
        try {
            while(h2Connection.getRS().next())
            {
                host = h2Connection.getRS().getString("ip");
                dbUsername = h2Connection.getRS().getString("username");
                dbPassword = h2Connection.getRS().getString("password");
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        h2Connection.closeConnection();
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent e)
    {
        username = usernameTF.getText();
        rawPassword = passwordTF.getText();

        algo = new PasswordEncryptionAlgorithm(rawPassword);
        algo.breakString(algo.split(algo.firstPass(rawPassword)));

        adminCon.loadDriver();
        adminCon.connectToDB(host, "admindb", dbUsername, dbPassword);   
        adminCon.doSomething("select *from admin where adminID = " + "'" + username + "'");
        adminCon.query();

        try
        {
            if(adminCon.getRS().next())
            {
                password = adminCon.getRS().getString("password");
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(password.equals(algo.getFinalPass()))
        {
            try
            {
                //CLOSE LOGIN WINDOW
                stage = (Stage) loginB.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();

                //LOAD ADMIN HOME WINDOW
                primaryStage = new Stage();
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/AdminStage.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            }
            catch(Exception f)
            {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }

            adminCon.closeConnection();     
            logWriter.writeLog(username, "LOGIN", host, dbUsername, dbPassword);            
            }
             else
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public void populateTable() throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/LogsTable.fxml"));
        innerAP.getChildren().setAll((AnchorPane) loader.load());

        MySQLConnection connection = new MySQLConnection();
        connection.loadDriver();

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        connection.connectToDB("localhost", "logsdb", "root", "forever");
        connection.doSomething("select *from logs");
        connection.query();

        for(int i = 0; i < connection.getRS().getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            final int j = i;

            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(connection.getRS().getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback <CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>()
            {

                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) 
                {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }

            });

            table.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        while(connection.getRS().next())
        {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for(int i = 1; i<= connection.getRS().getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                row.add(connection.getRS().getString(i));
            }

            data.add(row);
        }

        table.setItems(data);   
    }

    public void buttonClick(ActionEvent e) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        populateTable();
    }

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) 
    {

    }
}
```

AdminStage.fxml(Main frame)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mainBG" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="142.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Announcements" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="innerAP" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="835.0" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="226.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Logs" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Employees" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="394.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Students" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="478.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Backup" />
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="562.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Logout" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

LogsTable.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="491.0" prefWidth="367.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Aside: don't try to show `JOptionPane`s from the FX Application Thread - this will deadlock (hang) the application on many systems (including Mac OS X). Use a JavaFX `Dialog` instead. Also, I recommend properly typing your table view, table columns, and lists, and removing all the `@SuppressWarnings` from your code.

Comment: You have two FXML files: you should have two controller classes. Always use a different controller class for each FXML file. If you don't it becomes very difficult to track which instance of the controller has which fields initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Can you help me  find out why the table is not showing any data?

Comment: Your `populateTable` method is executed in the controller for `AdminStage.fxml`, which doesn't define a `table` element; so there is no `table` instantiated in this controller (seems to me that you should get a null pointer exception here). You need that code to be executed in the controller for `LogsTable.fxml`.